# Php QR code is not working for long length string

Tags: php, qr-code

I'm trying to convert my xml string to QR code.But it's showing nothing..It's working for minimal length string..Is there any way to do this?? here is my code

```
    <?php
    ob_start();
    include ('../includes/phpqrcode/qrlib.php');

    QRcode::png('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<vlsm>
<facility><facility_id>020175</facility_id>
<facility_name>Freda Rebecca Mine Clinic</facility_name>
<facility_state>Mashonaland Central</facility_state>
<facility_district>Bindura</facility_district>
<facility_hub_name></facility_hub_name>
<facility_sample_id></facility_sample_id>
<facility_request_clinician_name></facility_request_clinician_name>
<facility_request_clinician_phone_number></facility_request_clinician_phone_number>
<facility_support_partner></facility_support_partner>
<facility_physician_name></facility_physician_name>
<facility_date_test_ordered_by_physician>0000-00-00</facility_date_test_ordered_by_physician>
<facility_sample_collection_date>2017-03-06 06:00:00</facility_sample_collection_date>
<facility_sample_collected_by></facility_sample_collected_by>
<facility_mobile_numbers></facility_mobile_numbers>
<facility_emails></facility_emails>
<facility_test_urgency></facility_test_urgency>
</facility></vlsm>', "test.png", "L", 4, 4);
```

Comment: what happens when you output it to a browser directly?

Comment: It's showing QR code sometime, but sometime it's showing nothing.even not throwing error.It's showing just minimal content while scanning the generated QR code..this is the issue @RST